# How to get the tag-synonym data dump of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, data-dump

I want a data dump of the information at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms. How can I get that?

Answer (score 4):

There is a table in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) just for that: [TagSynonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/295232).

E.g. for [all synonyms with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all) you can just use the [following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/550078):

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM tagsynonyms
  WHERE sourcetagname LIKE '%c#%' OR targettagname LIKE '%c#%'
  ORDER BY creationdate
```

> [image]

Note that the data is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning.

Comment: But this can only get one or two, I need all? How to get it?

Comment: Well, then it's just easier: `SELECT * FROM tagsynonyms`.